# Pandas to_datetime parsing for oddly formatted date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-datetime, string-to-datetime

**TL;DR:**

How can I use format parameter in pd.to_datetime() to parse a date that is formatted as 'YYYY mmdd dd'?

**Background:**

I am pulling some data from an api and the index is a date but is formatted as a string. Here's what the index looks like:

```
Index(['2020 0422 22', '2020 0423 23', '2020 0424 24', '2020 0427 27',
       '2020 0428 28'],
      dtype='object')
```

**Option 1:**

Normally I would do something like `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)` and that would normally work like a charm. If that doesn't work, then I would use the format parameter to parse like this `pd.to_datetime(format='%y/%m/%d)` however given the fact that the day is included twice, I'm unsure how to use this parameter.

**Option 2:**

I could also use a string comprehension to create a new list, convert that to datetime, then set the index of df equal to that. Something like this:

```
[ x.split(' ')[0] + x.split(' ')[1] for x in df.tail().index ]
```

or

```
[ x[0:-2] for x in df.tail().index ]
```

But none of these options seem very pythonic

**The question:**

How can I use format parameter in pd.to_datetime() to parse a date that is formatted as 'YYYY mmdd dd'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) with `n=1` and selecting first list and then pass to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
idx = pd.Index(['2020 0422 22', '2020 0423 23', '2020 0424 24', '2020 0427 27',
       '2020 0428 28'])
df = pd.DataFrame(index = idx)

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.str.rsplit(n=1).str[0], format='%Y %m%d')
print (df)

Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2020-04-22 00:00:00, 2020-04-23 00:00:00, 
        2020-04-24 00:00:00, 2020-04-27 00:00:00, 
        2020-04-28 00:00:00]
```

Btw, most intuitive answer failed:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y %m%d %d')
print (df)
```

> error: redefinition of group name 'd' as group 4; was group 3